# trouble using refs for DOM of video tag fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

currently i am trying to see when my video tag is in fullscreen so i can change attributes of that specific video id/ref. I have tried many ways but the current way that i am about to show actually gave a console.log of the element. I have tried getElemementByID but this console.logs null and using a REF i can finally get my element but i cannot manipulate it or i might be doing it wrong.

the snippet is from the html side

```
 <video controls id= "myvideo" onMouseDown = 
    {this.changezindex} ref= {this.myRef} > <source src 
     = {mymov}/></video>
```

basically the only way i can access the ref is using a mousedown and that being clicked on the video works but not when i click full screen

```
  changezindex = () => {
      console.log("got clicked")
       const node = this.myRef.current;
        if (node.requestFullscreen) {
        //   node.requestFullscreen();
        console.log("got clickedd")
        }
```

this is getting called when i click on the video and it does console.log

recap- i'd like to gain access to the element when a user clicks on full screen so i can manipulate the attributes!
thanks for your help much appreciated

Comment: Video-react(https://video-react.js.org/) is a good package and fit in our case to get the event on full screen as it will give you lot of controls, you can find all controls and events on it here https://video-react.js.org/components/player/.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your video component is like,

```
 <video controls id= "myvideo" onMouseDown = {this.changezindex} ref= {this.myRef} > 
 <source src = {mymov}/>
 </video>
```

You can try getElementById in your componentDidMount(),

```
componentDidMount(){
   console.log(document.getElementById("myvideo"))
}
```

if you are able to capture the element in componentWillMount() you can do the following to assign a fullscreenchange event trigger,

```
componentDidMount(){
  document.getElementById("myvideo").addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', onFullScreen)
}
function onFullScreen(e) {

  alert('Fullscreen clicked' )
}
```

The  element can use one of the following three events:
1. webkitfullscreenchange
2. mozfullscreenchange
3. fullscreenchange